# Formula converted to arrayformula not working

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I want to convert below google sheet formula to arrayformula, please guide.

`=MAX(0,if((G3\>0)\*ISNUMBER(G3), MINUS((today()-K3),SUM(EOMONTH(K3,0)-K3,10)),G3))`

I want to convert this in array

basically k3 is a last date that i want to substract from todays date in a list

Answer (score 0):

You should add ranges instead of specific cells. So it should be something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((G3:G>0)*ISNUMBER(G3:G),(today()-K3:K)-((EOMONTH(K3:K, 0)-K3:K)+10), G3:G))
```

Comment: Error
Did not find value '2' in LOOKUP evaluation.

Comment: **Check here what result i am expecting**
**Check L3**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WQtCLIM6GKOnOHfOzrAvqmIS9MEuO77UxGUS2_vz5pw/edit#gid=1031975997

Comment: Thanks for the working sample, I have fixed the formula and updated the answer.

Comment: thanks david
i actually wanted the negative value to be zero but still this worked. Thanks

i was also trying to merge K3 and L3 formulas into one

Comment: I am glad it helped. You can accept the answer if that was the case.